# Android Studio GridLayout toggle all button

Tags: android, button, toggle, grid-layout

I'm using a Gridlayout with the MyView.java class. I got the code from [GridLayout](http://android-er.blogspot.de/2014/09/ongloballayoutlistener-called-repeatly.html).

I implemented another button under the GridLayout. I want to toggle all (GrigLayout-)Buttons with this button. Does anyone have an Idea how I could do this?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to revise through all child views, and check if they are toggle buttons. Here is an example, when you want to toggle, call `toggleButtons(grid);`

```
private void toggleButtons(ViewGroup v) { 
    View a; 
    for(int i = 0; i < v.getChildCount(); i++)
     {
        a = v.getChildAt(i); 
        if(a instanceof ViewGroup) {
            toggleButtons((ViewGroup) a); 
        }
        else if(a instanceof Button){ 
            // Toggle here
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! But my gridlayout isn't an instance of a ViewGroup or a Button, so it never reaches the toggle case.

is it correct that I have to hand the Gridlayout to the function?

Comment: Android GridLayout extends ViewGroup!